# Browser with HTML5 localStorage for Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: html, mobile, windows-mobile, local-storage

I know this was asked a year ago but I thought there might be some developments since then. I'm looking for a browser that has support for HTML5 localStorage or Google Gears for the Windows Mobile 6.5 platform. I know Gears is no longer being developed but IMO is still relevant if HTML5 localStorage has not yet hit the WM6 platform. I've tried:

**Dorothy browser**
Webkit based. Some sites suggest supports localStorage but I've tested on a WM 6.5 emulator and didn't work - maybe only for Android version.

**Opera Mini for WM 6.5**
Looks like may have some HTML5 support but no localStorage.

**Opera Mobile 10**
No HTML5 localStorage.

**Opera Mobile 9.5beta2**
No localStorage but Google Gears local database works (emulator). Problem is it's beta and officially doesn't exist according to Opera - no downloads available, I found it as a forum attachment. Also Opera have announced no more releases for WM.

**Internet Explorer Mobile 6**
No HTML5 localStorage but Google say it supports Gears, however gears.google.com tells me my browser is unsupported (using emulator), although I believe the useragent is identical to that of a physical WM 6.5 IEMobile6 device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Google Gears is supported only up to version 6.0 of Windows Mobile, it is marked unavailable for both IE and Opera (10.0) under Windows Mobile 6.5. I've found no link for Opera 10.5 download for WM, and as for 11, Opera announced it will no longer develop for WM.

Answer (score 2):

The site www.zetakey.com is claiming a HTML5 windows mobile/CE browser. Has anyone tried it? Going to give it a go on a Windows CE device (even though they recommend that it is not for end-users on that platform).

Comment: I downloaded and installed per instructions, but had quite a few problems. Can't blame them as they did say it wasn't recommended for end-users.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a beta build of Opera Mobile 11, which does have localStorage, for Windows phones: http://labs.opera.com/news/2011/03/22/ (it's not clear which version of the Windows OS it means though).

Comment: Looks like the Windows version of for Win7 desktop. Available downloads are shown at http://www.opera.com/mobile/download/versions/